# Jquery jsonp ajax callback not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am working on a sample example of implementing jsonp using jquery ajax .

Can someone please explain why the callback function 'customcb' is not getting invoked in below example , am confused.

From client application am making an $.ajax call to an ASP.NET MVC server application, below is the client code

```
$().ready(function () 
{

 $.ajax({
 url: 'http://localhost:55632/',
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 jsonp: 'cbqs',
 jsonpCallback: 'customcb',
 success: function (data) 
 {
 alert('success');
 },
 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
 {
  alert(errorThrown);
 }
 });

 function customcb() 
 {
  alert('customcb');
  }

});
```

And below is the simple ASP.net MVC action written in server application

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
public string Index()
{
 Emp x = new Emp
 {
  fname = "first name",
  lname = "last name"
 };

 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
 Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
 string str = "customcb(" + json + ")";
 return str;
 }
..............
..............
```

Expected Result: Both 'success' and 'customcb' alert messages should be displayed.

Actual Result : Only 'success' alert message is getting displayed.

Note : I am able to access the returned data from success function and there  are no JS errors.

Please let me know why 'customcb' alert message is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the jsonpCallback function out of "$().ready(function ()" code block.

```
function customcb() 
{
    alert('customcb');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with jsonp your response from the server should be of the form:

```
customcb({<JSON content>});
```

And your jsoncallback should be:

```
function customcb( o ) {
    console.log( o );
}
```

Comment: I have checked in fiddler , repsonse is 
customcb({"fname":"first name","lname":"last name"}), so I guess thats not the problem